# Is there a way to catch socket.io events without JavaScript in Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

My application handels a countdown, which refreshes all the time. The countdown itself is handeld by the server, like so:

```
@socketio.on("update-countdown")
def update_countdown():
   # do some stuff here to gather countdown
   socketio.emit("update-countdown", countdown)
```

Currently I am catching the event data in JavaScript like this:

```
var socket = io.connect();

var countdown_wrapper = document.getElementById("countdown");
socket.on("update-countdown", function(countdown) {
   countdown_wrapper.innerHTML = countdown;
});
```

---

**Q.:** Is there a way to catch socket.io events without JavaScript? If so, how could I do this?

Comment: Look at python-socketio if you want to do this without js: https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Not sure what the question is about: do you want to catch socket.io events without JavaScript _in the browser_? If so, I'm almost certain the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to replace javascript with python within your web browser's client-side code, you might want to look into https://brython.info/

It is essentially just using python within the browser. You wouldn't have all of those fancy decorators, but it would probably work well enough.